# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'freenect' - how to fix this?

Tags: python, ubuntu, kinect

I'm working on a project that requires python and some libraries. Almost everything works but there is one library that I can't get installed. It's about OpenKinect. You can find more information about it here: https://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page. I am running ubuntu desktop with python 3 installed.

i tried to install it using the instructions on the website but when i try to run it i get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'freenect'.

I want to make this project and improve it: https://www.instructables.com/How-You-Can-Make-a-Fully-Autonomous-Self-Driving-V/

All files are here: https://github.com/sieuwe1/Advanced-Real-Time-Self-Driving.

I've also tried to follow this guide: https://naman5.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/experimenting-with-kinect-using-opencv-python-and-open-kinect-libfreenect/ but when I try to install the necessary dependencies (step 2) I get this error:

```
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd... Klaar
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar 
Let op, 'git' wordt geselecteerd in plaats van 'git-core'
E: Kan pakket lubusb-1.0-0-dev niet vinden
E: Kon geen enkel pakket vinden via expansie (glob) 'lubusb-1.0-0-dev'
E: Kon geen enkel pakket vinden via regex 'lubusb-1.0-0-dev'
```

I leave it in Dutch to avoid mistakes.

When I type "cmake -L .." I get the following error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Operating system is Linux
-- Got System Processor x86_64
-- Linux x86_64 Detected
-- libfreenect will be installed to /usr/local
-- Headers will be installed to /usr/local/include/libfreenect
-- Libraries will be installed to /usr/local/lib
-- Found libusb-1.0:
--  - Includes: /usr/local/include/libusb-1.0
--  - Libraries: /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:315 (message):
  Policy CMP0072 is not set: FindOpenGL prefers GLVND by default when
  available.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0072" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  FindOpenGL found both a legacy GL library:

    OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

  and GLVND libraries for OpenGL and GLX:

    OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so

  OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE has not been set to "GLVND" or "LEGACY", so for
  compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  examples/CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking for module 'glut'
--   No package 'glut' found
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:315 (message):
  Policy CMP0072 is not set: FindOpenGL prefers GLVND by default when
  available.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0072" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  FindOpenGL found both a legacy GL library:

    OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

  and GLVND libraries for OpenGL and GLX:

    OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so

  OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE has not been set to "GLVND" or "LEGACY", so for
  compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  wrappers/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Checking for module 'glut'
--   No package 'glut' found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/marijn/libfreenect
-- Cache values
BUILD_AS3_SERVER:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_CPACK_DEB:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_CPACK_RPM:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_CPACK_TGZ:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_CPP:BOOL=ON
BUILD_CV:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_C_SYNC:BOOL=ON
BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=ON
BUILD_FAKENECT:BOOL=ON
BUILD_OPENNI2_DRIVER:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_PYTHON:BOOL=ON
BUILD_PYTHON2:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_PYTHON3:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_REDIST_PACKAGE:BOOL=ON
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local
CYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=CYTHON_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0
LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so
Python2_EXACTVERSION:STRING=
Python3_EXACTVERSION:STRING=
```

I hope someone knows how to fix this!

Comment: it would be simpler if you could give errors in English. Some commands may display in English if you put ie. `LANG=GB` before command.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: error shows `ImportError: No module named numpy`. You have to install `pip install numpy`

Comment: Hi, I've already done that but it says requirement already statisfied.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and you installed `numpy` in one Python but now you use different Python. Pythons don't share modules.